# regex to remove non alpha-words A-Z a-z from a list (exceptions)

Tags: python, regex, list

I am trying to remove words from a list of strings that contain non-alpha characters, for example:

```
["The", "sailor", "is", "sick", "."] -> ["The", "sailor", "is", "sick"]
```

But I cannot simply remove words that contain non-alpha chars at will because of possible cases like this:

```
["The", "U.S.", "is", "big", "."] -> ["The", "U.S.", "is", "big"] (acronym kept but period is removed)
```

I need to come up with a regex or some similar method that deals with simple cases like this (all types of punctuation):

```
["And", ",", "there", "she", "is", "."] -> ["And", "there", "she", "is"]
```

I use a natural language wrapper class that converts sentences into the the lists on the left but sometimes the lists are far more complex:

```
string:   "round up the "blonde bombshells' a all (well almost all)"
list: ["round", "up", "the", "''", "blonde", "bombshell", "\\", 
          "a", "all", "-lrb-", "well", "almost", "all", "-rrb-"]
```

As you can see some characters such as parentheses and apostrophes are converted or removed by the wrapper. I would like to get rid of all these extraneous substrings into a cleaner looking:

```
list: ["round", "up", "the", "blonde", "bombshell",
          "a", "all", "well", "almost", "all"]
```

I am fairly new to python am under the impression that a regex would be my best approach here but do not how to convert the first list to the cleaned up second list and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to fit your description:

```
cases=[
    ["The", "sailor", "is", "sick", "."],
    ["The", "U.S.", "is", "big", "."],
    ["round", "up", "the", "''", "blonde", "bombshell", "\\", 
    "a", "all", "-lrb-", "well", "almost", "all", "-rrb-"],
]

import re

for li in cases:
    print '{}\n\t->{}'.format(li, [w for w in li if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]', w)])
```

Prints:

```
['The', 'sailor', 'is', 'sick', '.']
    ->['The', 'sailor', 'is', 'sick']
['The', 'U.S.', 'is', 'big', '.']
    ->['The', 'U.S.', 'is', 'big']
['round', 'up', 'the', "''", 'blonde', 'bombshell', '\\', 'a', 'all', '-lrb-', 'well', 'almost', 'all', '-rrb-']
    ->['round', 'up', 'the', 'blonde', 'bombshell', 'a', 'all', 'well', 'almost', 'all']
```

Which, if correct, you can do without a regex at all:

```
for li in cases:
    print '{}\n\t->{}'.format(li, [w for w in li if w[0].isalpha()])
```

Comment: I don't have to print the list (just return it). Just wondering if the following is sufficient for a case. Sorry I'm pretty new to python, I know this is list comprehension so this seems to be correct                                             
    li = [w for w in li if w[0].isalpha()])

Comment: Then you would do `def f(li): return [w for w in li if w[0].isalpha()])` -- done.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [punctuation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.punctuation) to do this:

```
>>> from string import punctuation
>>> [i for i in lst if i not in punctuation]   
['The', 'U.S.', 'is', 'big']
```

Answer (score 1):

By making sure every string contains at least one alphanumeric:

```
import re

expr = re.compile(r"\w+")
test = ["And", ",", "there", "she", "is", ".", "U.S."]

filtered = [v for v in test if expr.search(v)]
print(filtered)
```

prints

```
['And', 'there', 'she', 'is', 'U.S.']
```

Alternatives would be excluding numbers, and making sure the string doesn't start with a non-alpha character:

```
# only alpha
expr = re.compile(r"[a-zA-Z]+")
test = ["round", "up", "the", "''", "blonde", "bombshell", "\\",
        "a", "all", "-lrb-", "well", "almost", "all", "-rrb-"]
# use match() here
filtered = [v for v in test if expr.match(v)]
print(filtered)
```

prints

```
['round', 'up', 'the', 'blonde', 'bombshell', 'a', 'all', 'well', 'almost', 'all']
```

Comment: Doesn't work for the last string ["round", "up", "the", "''", "blonde", "bombshell", "\\", "a", "all", "-lrb-", "well", "almost", "all", "-rrb-"]

Comment: Works fine for me on Python 3.5

Comment: close but this doesn't work for the blonde bombshell case, I am using python 2.7 because the wrapper class is specific to python 2 unfortunately it cannot be done in python3